# Is there any way to concatenate a value in a column with different strings?

Tags: mysql, concat

[image]

As you can see on the column 'Race Position' I have a set of values corresponding to the participants results. 1 being 1st Position and so on.

What I wanted was to be able to concat the values and give the first 3 strings as so; 1'st', 2'nd', 3'rd'. The position after will all finish with 'th' at the end for example 4th, 5th, 6th ,7th and so on.

Is there any way to implement this? I have used a cross join in order to make my positions work.

Comment: Looks like you're aware of the `concat()` function; what's your problem with using it?

Answer (score 1):

I have the generic expression you need:

```
SELECT CONCAT(@num,IF(MOD(@num,100) IN (11,12,13),'th',
IF(MOD(@num,10) IN (1,2,3),SUBSTR('stndrd',2*MOD(@num,10)-1,2),'th')));
```

What this does is the following

- If the last digit of a number is 1 (other than last two digits being 11), `st` is appended
- If the last digit of a number is 2 (other than last two digits being 12), `nd` is appended
- If the last digit of a number is 3 (other than last two digits being 13), `rd` is appended
- All other two-digit combinations have `th` appended

To test this out, run the following

```
SELECT CONCAT(num,IF(MOD(num,100) IN (11,12,13),'th',
IF(MOD(num,10) IN (1,2,3),SUBSTR('stndrd',2*MOD(num,10)-1,2),'th'))) n FROM
(SELECT th*1000+h*100+t*10+u num FROM
(SELECT 0 th UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) TH,
(SELECT 0 h UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) H,
(SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) T,
(SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) U) A
ORDER BY num;
```

## UPDATE 2017-04-13 14:29 EDT

[You asked me](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/170863/is-there-any-way-to-concatenate-a-value-in-a-column-with-different-strings/170866#comment330102_170866)

> Hey Rolando, I understand roughly how you have implemented this. But How would I work this around my code as so; select id, duration, @position := @position + 1 as position from (select @position := 0) x, (select id, duration from course order by duration asc) y;

```
SELECT id,CONCAT(position,IF(MOD(position,100) IN (11,12,13),'th',
IF(MOD(position,10) IN (1,2,3),SUBSTR('stndrd',2*MOD(position,10)-1,2),'th')))
FROM 
(
    select id, duration, @position := @position + 1 as position
    from (select @position := 0) x,
    (select id, duration from course order by duration asc) y
) a;
```

Basically, I placed your query inside a subquery and applied the generic expression.

Comment: Hey Rolando, I understand roughly how you have implemented this. But How would I work this around my code as so;

`select id, duration, @position := @position +  1 as position
from
       (select @position := 0) x,
       (select id, duration
        from course
        order by duration asc) y;`

Answer (score 0):

Not a MySQL guy but this code should be fairly close to what you need. It's slightly more involved than just Concat();

```
SELECT 
CASE
  WHEN right(RacePosition,1)=1 and RacePosition not like '11' THEN Concat(RacePosition ,'st')
  WHEN right(RacePosition,1)=2 and RacePosition not like '12' THEN Concat(RacePosition ,'nd')
  WHEN right(RacePosition,1)=3 and RacePosition not like '13' THEN Concat(RacePosition ,'rd')
  ELSE Concat(RacePosition,'th')
  END AS RaceOrder,
 ParticipantID,
 ContactNumber,
 Duration,
 EventName
 FROM RaceData
 Order by RacePosition;
```

If you have some complex cross-join query, that you don't want to mess with just embed it as a table like so:

```
  SELECT 
    CASE
     WHEN right(RacePosition,1)=1 and RacePosition not like '11'  THEN Concat(RacePosition ,'st')
     WHEN right(RacePosition,1)=2 and RacePosition not like '12'  THEN Concat(RacePosition ,'nd')
     WHEN right(RacePosition,1)=3 and RacePosition not like '13'  THEN Concat(RacePosition ,'rd')
     ELSE Concat(RacePosition,'th')
     END AS RaceOrder,
    ParticipantID,
    ContactNumber,
    Duration,
    EventName
    FROM
    (<my complex query>) t
    Order by RacePosition;
```

Or perhaps:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
      WHEN RacePosition in (11,12,13) THEN Concat( RacePosition ,'th')
      WHEN right(RacePosition,1)=1 THEN Concat(RacePosition ,'st')
      WHEN right(RacePosition,1)=2 THEN Concat(RacePosition ,'nd')
      WHEN right(RacePosition,1)=3 THEN Concat(RacePosition ,'rd')
      ELSE Concat(RacePosition,'th')
      END AS RaceOrder,
     ParticipantID,
     ContactNumber,
     Duration,
     EventName
     FROM RaceData
     Order by RacePosition;
```

Comment: This does not work for 11, 12, 13, 111, 112, 113, 211, 212, 213, etc.

Comment: I would think 11th, 12th, 13th, 112th, 113th, 211th, etc would be fine...

Comment: if your ordering is out of sequence because RacePosition is character rather than int, just order by duration.

Comment: My mistake, I said it backwards. I meant it would not work for 21st, 22nd, 23rd, 121st, 122nd, 123rd, etc.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I changed my code to match your comments/request.